# Neo4j is returning No Value for cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a duration column in a csv file with the following format: "0:00:00".
I created these nodes in Neo4j:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS line
CREATE (testnode: Event {
  tph: toInteger(substring(line.Dur,0,1)),
  tpm: toInteger(substring(line.Dur,2,2)),
  tps: toInteger(substring(line.Dur,5,2))
})
```

Then I typed the following query to create a duration:

```
MATCH (n:Event)
UNWIND duration({hours: n.tph, minutes: n.tpm, seconds: n.tps}) AS duration
RETURN duration.minutes
```

Neo4j answer was: hours must be a number value, but was a NoValue.
Maybe this is a wrong way to create durations using a map, I need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can unwind a duration. Only lists can be unwinded. You probably want to use `WITH` instead of `UNWIND`.

```sql
MATCH (n:Event)
WITH duration({hours: n.tph, minutes: n.tpm, seconds: n.tps}) AS duration
RETURN duration.minutes
```